# Подключение внешней таблицы к серверу MySQL

Tags: mysql

Имеется сервер MySQL с базой. Можно ли к нему напрямую подключить таблицу чтоб джойнить с таблицами базы? Попытка сделать temporary table и загрузить в нее из csv не увенчалась успехом - нет доступа - не дает создать временную таблицу. Аккаунта с большими привилегиями нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: что  в вашем представлении "внешняя" таблица? Есть Federated engine там можно сделать алиас на таблицу на другом сервере, это наверное, будет внешним, но раз у вас прав на создание временных нет, то на такое и подавно, видимо не будет. Получайте права на создание временных таблиц. и то не совсем ясно, как вы туда собирались и csv вливать и джойнить в одном подключении.

Comment: Кроме [The FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html), есть ещё и [The CSV Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html), который позволяет обращаться к лежащим внутри локального CVS файла данным как к таблице. Но CSV-файл должен гарантированно не содержать ошибок и погрешностей. Кроме того, настоятельно рекомендую обойтись доступом только на чтение.

Comment: @teran Под "внешней" я подразумевал файлик в папке с программой. Но не суть. Я уже узнал что прав на текущем аккаунте совсем нет - даже дамп таблицы сделать нельзя. Я решил поступить другим образом - прикрутил к программе SQLite и все делать в ней, а MYSQL-таргет использовать только для получения нужных данных - читать то не запрещено. Вот только не могу кое-какую таблицу перенести из MySQL в SQLite последовательно через переменную(с дампом было бы проще, но увы).